# Spring boot validation CGLIB enhanced controller components not autowired

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-validator, cglib, nhibernate-validator

I have created a spring boot application (user spring-boot-starter-parent V. 2.2.2.RELEASE) with Rest controllers, that work fine, now I have added a dependency to :

```
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
    </dependency>
```

And have added @Validated on my controller class so that all methods in it should be validated:

```
@RestController
@Validated 
public class UserController {
  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    System.out.println("test");
  }
}
```

Now the controller methods when called start throwing NullPointerExceptions because the userService is null; I did a @PostConstruct as a test. Apparently it is called on a normal unenhanced bean which has the fields autowired correctly. But when calling the controller through HTTP, this unenhanced bean is not called, but it is a bean of class UserController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ and it has the userController not autowired. I don't really know why cause this is supposed to be really simple, there is not much to configure as far as I know. So I guess for some reason spring does not inject dependencies to CGLIB enhanced classes or just injects it into a wrong class. When I remove @Validated, everything is working fine again, but there is no validation of course.

Answer (score 6):

This was the most ridiculous error I had for ages. I mistakenly set controller methods in my original project as private. This caused the CGLIB to not enhance them and instead just have them with original code. Spring did not complain and is happy to run those methods

Comment: Good, glad you found it. Thanks for sharing your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your supplied code and making a dummy `UserService` class, HTTP requests work fine in other environments.

To help solve the issue you're having, you should create a new project, adding the `lombok`, `starter-web`, and `starter-validation` dependencies. Create the following classes.

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public int test(){
        return userService.getAge();
    }
}
```

---

```
@Data
@Service
public class UserService {
    private int age = 21;
}
```

Then test `http://localhost:8080/test`

If this doesn't work for you, then you should try invalidating your cache and restarting your IDE. Intellij has an option for that if you click on `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart ...`. Alternatively, you can delete the artifacts (or the full local repo) from your .m2 folder. `C:\Users\<username>\.m2\repository` and rebuild with maven.

If this still doesn't solve your issue, please update your question with a more complete reproducible example of your problem along with a full console log of your error, and I will update my answer.

Comment: ok first I have checked it independently of IDE, by running it with mvn spring-boot:run with the same effect. Then I created a project with same libraries, basic stuff and rest controller. It turned out everything works fine and objects are validated. I placed the breakpoint inside the controller method, and saw that "this" is a plain class that has the field autowired. While in the original project this is a class $$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ class that has the fields not autowired. It also has CGLIB$CALLBACK_1.target referencing the original class

Comment: it also contains reference to proxy factory: org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory: 0 interfaces []; 1 advisors [org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [AnnotationMatchingPointcut: org.springframework.aop.support.annotation.AnnotationClassFilter: interface org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated, MethodMatcher.TRUE]; 

So this also must have come from validation. I am not sure what are the differences, there are no special annotations in the original project configuration

Comment: ok that was super stupid mistake that took me hours to notice. In the original project controller methods were private and that caused the effect, I cannot delete my question now :/